# how to ensure that my tables are created using try catch and to find out why my code is giving error I am new to node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench, sql-view, qsqlquery

I have a nodejs script which creates dynamic tables and views  for the temperature recorded for the day. it does not create tables if the temp is not in the normal range s. how do I ensure that this does not happen again. i am new to node and did not find anything that will help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should add error processing into you query function:

```js
    let execute_query = function(query) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        con.query(query, function(err, result, fields) {
           if (err) {
             reject(err);
           } else {
             console.log(query);
             resolve(1);
           }
         });
       });
     }
```

and then eclose for loop into try...catch. That way you will be able to understand the issue:

```js
  try {
     for ....
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

Comment: Iwant to make sure tht if the error occurs it will create a table for that temp .can you tell me how to do that

Comment: You said you have an error, didn't you? or did I miss something? You should first analyse your error before ensuring anything.

Comment: yeah it creates tables sometimes i want to make sure it creates always. the error occurs at con.query